# How to implement fmt::Display on a recursive data structure in Rust

Tags: rust, recursive-datastructures

I tried to provide an implementation of the Display trait on the recursive data structure Tree as defined below.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree <'a> {
    node: (&'a str, Vec<Tree<'a>>)
}

impl <'a> Tree<'a> {
   fn new(str: &'a str) -> Tree<'a> {
    Tree {node: (str, Vec::new())}
   }

   pub fn merge_sub (&mut self, sub: Tree<'a>) {
    self.node.1.push(sub); 
   }
}

fn main(){
 
    let ta = Tree::new("a");
    let mut tb = Tree::new("b");
    tb.merge_sub(ta);

    let tc = Tree::new("c");
    let mut td = Tree::new("d");
    td.merge_sub(tc);

    let te = Tree::new("e");
    let mut tf = Tree::new("f");
    tf.merge_sub(te);


    let mut tg = Tree::new("g");
    tg.merge_sub(tb);
    tg.merge_sub(td);
    tg.merge_sub(tf);
    println!("sub tree g: {:#?}.", tg);
    println!("Display: {}.", tg);
}
```

Hopefully, the `println!("Display: {}.", tg);` would render in the format like this below :

```
   |--b--a
   |
g--|--d--c
   |
   |--f--e
```

The challenge here is that the **fmt** function and **write!** macro may not be the best fit for my requirements. Because I need to manipulate the string representation of inductive cases specifically, while these tools provide more general, high-level functionalities.

```
impl<'a> fmt::Display for Tree<'a>{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result{
        let length = self.node.1.len();
        if length == 0{
            return write!(f, "{}", self.node.0)
        }else{
            for (i,t) in self.node.1.iter().enumerate(){ 
                // How to get recursive show instance of Tree ?
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question when you take into account that the core of it is "how do I automatically generate a horizontal ASCII graph from a tree structure." The answer is non-trivial.

Comment: Certainly the standard formatting traits aren't doing you any favors. The most sensible solution would likely construct the visual layout as a `String`, `Vec<String>`, or whatever is most convenient, and then printing *that*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) and [`ToString::to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) to convert something that implements `Display` into a `String` you can work with, that gives us [this simplistic implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a919122066ba9577d23646b0b438f24):

```rust
        } else {
            let mut sub_nodes = self
                .node
                .1
                .iter()
                .map(ToString::to_string)
                .intersperse("\n\n".into())
                .collect::<String>()
                .split('\n')
                .map(ToString::to_string)
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            let len = sub_nodes.len();
            if len == 1 {
                return write!(f, "{}--{}", self.node.0, sub_nodes[0]);
            }
            for (i, sn) in sub_nodes.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                if len / 2 == i {
                    *sn = format!("{}--|--{}", self.node.0, sn);
                } else {
                    if sn == "" {
                        *sn = format!("   |   ");
                    } else {
                        *sn = format!("   |--{}", sn);
                    }
                }
            }
            write!(f, "{}", sub_nodes.join("\n"))
        }
```

Note: This code assumes all node identifiers are 1 character wide and that any subtree only contains a linked list, to make this work properly with any trees you have to output the corresponding amount of spaces or dashes and further special case the different possibilities of `sn`.